# Show row in section with same name of row value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a Struct of products, taken from Firebase db, like this:

```
struct Product {
    var name: String
    var type: String
    var ingredients: String
    var price: Double
}
```

and i want to populate a tableview with section (product type) and relative rows.
So I created an array with all product type:

```
let array = product.compactMap{$0.type}
```

Then i have removed duplicates and i used final array for numberofSection and titleForHeaderInSections and it works.
But now i want to show in each section only products with same type of section name.
How can I work on this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return product.count
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can group your products in a dictionary by type

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: product, by: { $0.type})
```

and then access that using your array of types

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let type = typesArray[section]
    guard let count = dict[type]?.count else {
        return 0
    }
    return count
}
```

Another option would be to creating the dictionary directly with the array index as key so it can be used directly in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

```
Dictionary(grouping: product, by: { typesArray.firstIndex(of: prod.type)! })
```

Comment: Thanks!  Have you a solution for showing relative rows in each section? I'm trying with some things in cellForRowAt but i can't find the way

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you get the rows foe each row from the dictionary.

Comment: in my cellForRowat i have this: if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.productName.text = product[indexPath.row].name

Comment: i'm not familiar with this type of arrays, can you explain me how to configurate cellForRowAt please?

Comment: You get the type the same way as above but you use indexPath.section and then you get the array as dict[type] and use indexPath.row to get the row from the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can add struct Category for easier data manipulation. Just make a category for all product types and filter de the products that you need. With an array of categories that contains an array of products you will have all the information you need: products, count, type etc...

```
struct Category {
    var type: String
    var products: [Product]
}

let allProducts = [Product]()
let categorySet: Set<String> = allProducts.map({ $0.type }).toSet()

let categorys: [Category] = categorySet.map { (type) -> T in
        return Category(type: type, products: allProducts.filter({ $0.type == type}) )
 }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categorys.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return categorys[section].products.count
}


func tableView( tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String
{

return categorys[section].type

}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return product.filter { $0.type == "myType" }.count
}
```